# Facebook login plugin

Tags: facebook, plugins

If I enable faces, once logged in it becomes really big and obtrusive to my page.

If I disable faces, once logged in the login box remains.

Am I doing something wrong or is this intentional? Surely a log out option would seem more logical...

Answer (score 0):

Just play a little bit with the Login Plugin parameters

- **width** the width of the plugin in pixels. Default width: 200px
- **max-rows** the maximum number of rows of profile pictures to
  display. Default value: 1

So you can adjust the plugin to your page layout. Notice that the plugin sizes its height; if you specify a maximum of 5 rows of faces, and there are only enough faces to fill 3, the height of the plugin will be automatically sized using only the room it needs.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Comment: Is there not supposed to be a logout button? This would be odd considering it's in their terms of service that there should be a clearly visible option to log out of Facebook...

Comment: I've just noticed "Note: If the user is already logged in, no login button is shown." on the page linked, which isn't the case either. I'm left with a login button either way,

Comment: I think you must understand that login plugin is just that, a login button, if the user is already login in facebook, faces appear and no login button is displayed, there's no logout feature, facebook won't allow third parties websites logout their members. IMAO.

Comment: Actually you can get a logout link by setting an undocumented (or not very well documented, I can't find anything about it) parameter, `data-autologoutlink` (or `autologoutlink` if you're using XFBML), to `true`.